# Connecting to File Geodatabases from ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: file-geodatabase, arcgis-pro, mxd

I have File Geodatabases that I created in ArcCatalog and ArcMap 10.5.  I am trying to open maps in ArcGIS Pro from these File Geodatabases, but when using the "import Map" tool only folders show up, and no Geodatabases.  If I use the "+Connections >> Add Database >> Select Existing Geodatabase" tool my file Geodatabases show up and I can connect to them, but none of the .mxd files are shown, only feature classes, toolboxes, python scripts, and .csv's.

How do I connect to a .mxd file within a file Geodatabase in ArcGIS Pro?

[image: picture of opening map in .gdb]
[image: saving map in .gdb]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your picture it appears that you have saved an MXD file into the same Windows folder that contains the files making up your file geodatabase.

I think that is an unwise practice.

From [your comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270169/connecting-to-file-geodatabases-from-arcgis-pro#comment429847_270169) it appears that moving the MXD file out of the file geodatabase's folder has resolved this for you.